# Why weren't Marty2 and Biff at the stairs in BTTF?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

In Back to the Future, when Marty takes Lorraine to the dance there is no-one at the stairs when he drives in...

[image]

But in BTTF2 it's revealed that another Marty and Biff were at the stairs the same time Marty1 comes to the dance...

[image]

From a purely **in-universe perspective**, why weren't Marty2 and Biff at the stairs in the first movie?

Comment: Because traveling in time has the potential to spawn new timelines; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WolcbNTNX5I

Comment: what do you mean english please

Comment: Which particular word were you unfamiliar with?

Comment: no i mean ti dont know what this means Because traveling in time has the potential to spawn new timelines how does that mean for another Marty and Biff were at the stairs the same time Marty1 comes to the dance...

Comment: They weren't there the first time around because Marty hadn't traveled back in time to be there yet. When he went back the second time, he insinuated himself into an existing timeline.

Comment: but when marty sings johhny b goode i saw a shadow in the distance on the right behind a pink prop i thought that was marty 2 in the first movie

Comment: The writers (Gale and Zemeckis) hadn't even come up with the story of BTTF 2 when they wrote and filmed the original (they didn't even plan on a sequel in fact), so there couldn't have been any intentional foreshadowing of Marty 2 in the first movie.

Comment: how when marty sings johhny b goode i saw a shadow in the distance on the right behind a pink prop i thought that was marty 2 in the first movie how could of thatnot of have been him

Comment: Would you consider asking a separate question about the shadow and whether it might have been meant to be Marty 2 (preferably with a screenshot)? Then people could give you evidence that it wasn't meant to be him--it wouldn't really be on-topic for your question above.

Comment: @AndrewCasali "TI don't know what this means"? TI the rapper?

Comment: In universe: They were missing from BTTF  because in BTTF,  BTTF2 hadn't happened yet. Word.

Comment: what do you mean hasent happened yet itt was the same night same events same thing

Comment: No. There weren't additional time travelers in BTTF because BTTF 2s timeline had not yet been created. So, everything in BTTF 2 happened on the same day as BTTF, but not in the same timeline. When the BTTF 2 time travelers arrive, they create an additional timeline in which everything was the same as BTTF until the BTTF 2 players arrived.

Comment: not in the same timeline what do you mean its the same night same events happing at the same time

Comment: Do we know that when the first picture is captured, the second event was happening ?

Comment: Yep Marty 2 noticed Marty 1 drying in the parking lot with his binoculars on the stairs in both pictures

Comment: Apparently, time travel in Back to the Future doesn’t work how you think it works. And just to *really* blow your mind: the shadow you saw behind the pink prop *isn’t Marty2*.

Comment: then were was marty 2 in the gym when he was singing johnny b goode

Comment: Dude. What do you mean what do we mean? Please explain why none of us seems to be able to clearly comment on or answer the question, 'cause normally no one likes beating a dead horse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's not how time travel works in BTTF.

- The first movie shows how the timeline is freshly rewritten into the one where George stood up to Biff.
- From that new present's future, old Biff travelled back to rewrite the timeline again by providing young Biff with the Almanac.
- *Then* Marty2 arrives back in the past and is on the stairs. From his point of view, his previous travel has happened, so he's seeing his past self. But from Marty1's point of view, which BTTF1 shows, BTTF2 will not yet have happened and thus the scene shows no Marty2.

Comment: Actually from Marty1's point of view at that point he would have seen Marty2 if he'd just looked to the right, but yes in BTTF1 he wouldn't have.

Comment: @zabeus Marty1 spotting Marty2 would (to paraphrase Doc Brown) a) have caused Marty1 to faint like Jennifer (and thus fail his mission and make him cease exist) b) torn the space-time continuum apart or maybe c) split the universe into two (one where Marty1 didn't spot Marty2 and one where he did)